# Facebook friend request using Graph 2.0 SDK

Tags: java, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app that has a requirement to send a friend request to the facebook app or at least re-direct to the facebook website.

I have taken a look at the Graph 2.0 SDK and I noticed that the friends dialog was removed. Similarly having looked at similar posts on Stackoverflow it appears as though this may have been possible at one point but not anymore?

Is someone able to confirm or suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: There is no way to do that